# How to keep the SQLite database file in RAM?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Okay I know this question feels weird, but let me present my problem. I am building Qt based application with SQLite as my database. I noticed a few things. Whenever you are performing operations like manipulating row one by one directly on the sqlite file, it seems slow. That is because it is doing I/O operations on a file which is stored in hard drive. But when I use SSD instead of HDD, the speed is considerably improved, that is because SSD has high IO speed. But if I load a table into QSqlTableModel, we can make all the changes and save it the speed is good. That is because in one query the data is fetched from sqlite file and stored in RAM memory. And So the IO operations are less. So it got me thinking is it possible to save the sqlite file in RAM when my application launches, perform all my opeartions and then when user chooses to close, at that instant i can save the file to HDD? One might think why don't I just use qsqltablemodel itself, but there are some cases for me which involves creating tables and deleting tables, which qt doesnt support out of box, we need to execute query for that. So if anyone can point me if there's a way to achieve this in Qt, that would be great!

Comment: Is this really anything to do with `Qt` or is it simply that you want to be able to save/restore a memory based sqlite database?  If it's the latter then [this might be of some help](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html).

Comment: @G.M Yes, since I am using Qt provided drivers for connection with SQLite I was hoping if there is any Qt way of doing it. Thanks for the link I will look into it.

Comment: Why not use transactions to bundle I/O? Anyway, you can open SQLite files in memory by choosing ":memory:" as database name. See https://forum.qt.io/topic/8879/solved-saving-and-restoring-an-in-memory-sqlite-database